# linux inotify returns same watch descriptor as before

Tags: linux-kernel, inotify

I have a program which uses linux `inotify` syscall to monitor files generated in a folder.
The program monitors the file sizes, so uses a `IN_MODIFY` flag for the file. Since file could be written at a fast rate, and we don't want `inotify` queue to get overflowed, the mask also uses `IN_ONESHOT` mask which makes `inotify` to delete the watch when it sends an event for file modification. The program then adds a watch again. and the process repeats, as described in the following loop.

`eventLoop`:

1. program adds a watch on a file, gets a watch fd (say `a0`)
2. file gets modified, program gets an event on watch fd `a0`
3. (since `IN_ONESHOT` was used, the watch is auto deleted by inotify now.)
4. program handles the modify (`0x2`) event and does its logic
5. program adds a watch again on the same file, gets a new watch fd (say `a1`) (this step is same as step 1.)

While testing it is observed that after some iterations of the above loop, the watch fd returned in the step 5 is same as one returned in step 1. and once this happens, there are no more events received for file changes. the loop essentially halts.

To find out more about the behavior, I executed the same program under `strace`, the same problem occurs, but after a really long time. If earlier this was occurring in 2 minutes, with `strace` this problem occurs after 3-4 hours. But it does occur.

Is this a known issue? Am i doing something wrong in my code? (The code is in `golang`, and running in a container on a kubernetes cluster)

Just the fact that under `strace` the problem takes longer to appear make me wonder if the problem lies inside `inotify`. (I am figuring out how to trace the kernel, but i may not succeed in that)

**Update**
I modified the program to add a retry if the watch fd returned by `inotify` is same as the old one. After adding this retry in a loop makes the program to continue the expected behavior.

Comment: Do not *describe* your code. Any description misses a details which could be important for the problem. Instead, paste that code into the post (in form of [mcve]).

Comment: what would you like to know, i can provide details

Comment: What is a "watch fd"? There is no such thing in inotify API. Did you mean a watch descriptor?

Comment: yes, watch fd is watch  descriptor